# CollectTop is returning more rows than I would expect in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have the following input (testing in the Azure portal) that I have uploaded:

```
[
  {"engineid":"engine001","eventtime":1,"tmp":19.3,"hum":0.22},
  {"engineid":"engine001","eventtime":2,"tmp":19.7,"hum":0.21},
  {"engineid":"engine002","eventtime":3,"tmp":20.4,"hum":0.25},
  {"engineid":"engine001","eventtime":4,"tmp":19.6,"hum":0.24}
]
```

Then I try to get the records group, so that I have the 2 last rows for every engine.  As you can see in the sample, I only have 2 different engines, so I would expect an output with two records that each contain the ranked records, but I am getting 4 output records.

This is my query:

```
-- Taking relevant fields from the input stream
WITH RelevantTelemetry AS
(
    SELECT  engineid, tmp, hum, eventtime
    FROM    [engine-telemetry] 
    WHERE   engineid IS NOT NULL
),
-- Grouping by engineid in TimeWindows
TimeWindows AS
(
    SELECT engineid, 
        CollectTop(2) OVER (ORDER BY eventtime DESC) as TimeWindow
    FROM
        [RelevantTelemetry]
    WHERE engineid IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY SlidingWindow(hour, 24), engineid
)
--Output timewindows for verification purposes
SELECT TimeWindow
INTO debug
FROM TimeWindows
```

I played with the TIMESTAMP BY property, changed the order of GROUP BY, etc, but still I keep having the following 4 records, rather than the 2 I was expecting:

Any idea?

```
[
{"TimeWindow":
  [
    {"rank":1,"value": "engineid":"engine001","tmp":0.0003,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":1}}
  ]},
{"TimeWindow":
  [
    {"rank":1,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0019,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":4}},
    {"rank":2,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0026,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":2}},
    {"rank":3,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":0.0003,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":1}}
  ]},
{"TimeWindow":
  [
    {"rank":1,"value":{"engineid":"engine002","tmp":0.0017,"hum":0.0003,"eventtime":3}}
  ]},
{"TimeWindow":
  [
    {"rank":1,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0019,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":4}},
    {"rank":2,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0026,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":2}}
  ]}
]
```

Comment: Have you try to use `GROUP BY TumblingWindow(hour, 24), engineid`?

Comment: thanks, steve - that seems to do the trick indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @SteveZhao, you need to use `GROUP BY TumblingWindow(hour, 24), engineid` instead of `GROUP BY SlidingWindow(hour, 24), engineid`

Sliding window can overlap entries based on time interval[image]

For more information refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions

Comment: Thanks, Pranav & Steve.  That seems to drive better results. I thought sliding window would always keep the latest N records available and am afraid that TumblingWindow might not have N records, if they cross the boundary and a new Window has started...