# How to convert a 'dictionary-like' structure in Azure Stream Analytics to a multi dimensional array with a javascript UDF?

Tags: azure, user-defined-functions, azure-stream-analytics

After using the `CollectTop` aggregation function of Azure Stream Analytics, I get back a json-like structure that seems to be like a Dictionary of Dictionaries.
I need to convert this one to a multi-dimensional array which I want to pass to an AzureML UDF.

My question is mostly on how I can interpret this structure in a javascript-UDF, as I'm totally new to Javascript.

This is a sample record (using `CollectTop`), but the challenge is how my javascript UDF should look like?

```
[
    {"rank":1,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0019,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":4}},
    {"rank":2,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0026,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":2}},
    {"rank":3,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":0.0003,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":1}}
]
```

From the above data structure, I'd love to get the following array generated. (taking tmp & hum fields)

```
[[-0.0019, -0.0002], [-0.0026, -0.0002], [0.0003, -0.0002]]
```

Any help or insights are welcome.

This question is related to two other questions:

- [CollectTop is returning more rows than I would expect in Azure Stream Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267072/collecttop-is-returning-more-rows-than-i-would-expect-in-azure-stream-analytics/63296208#63296208)
- [Call Azure Stream Analytics UDF with multi-dimensional array of last 5 records, grouped by record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187116/call-azure-stream-analytics-udf-with-multi-dimensional-array-of-last-5-records?noredirect=1#comment111750919_63187116)

Best regards

Comment: What's your multi-dimensional array like?Can you show us a sample of your multi-dimensional array's structure you expected.

Comment: Hello @SteveZhao - thx for the feedback.  I have updated my question with the desired array outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input = [
        {"rank":1,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0019,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":4}},
        {"rank":2,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":-0.0026,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":2}},
        {"rank":3,"value":{"engineid":"engine001","tmp":0.0003,"hum":-0.0002,"eventtime":1}}
    ];
    
    console.log(getOutput(input));
    
    
    function getOutput(input){
        var output = [];
        for(var x in input){
            var array = [];
            array.push(input[x].value.tmp);
            array.push(input[x].value.hum);
            output.push(array);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Is this your needed?

Comment: That, sir, is exactly what I needed ;). Thanks for this...